Display grid: Edge to edge grid rows (no space after last row item) How?
Please see this playground https://play.tailwindcss.com/SMkXmO9Mo8
As the text say I want the grid row items to distribute evenly and edge to edge in a container with flexible width.
justify-content: space-between; or tailwinds justify-beween has no effect on grid only flex.


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

But basically you can't. Each child is positioned inside it's own grid-column which has no spatial relationship to the child's position in the grid
You would have to institute a column-gap based on the number of columns and the width of the children.. so something like column-gap: calc((100% - (6 * 2em)) / 5).


.grid {
  background: lightblue;
  column-gap: calc((100% - (6 * 2em)) / 5) !important;
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="grid w-[400px] gap-0 grid-cols-6 gap-y-4 bg-slate-300">
  <span class="flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded bg-green-500">1</span>
  <span class="flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded bg-green-500">2</span>
  <span class="flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded bg-green-500">3</span>
  <span class="flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded bg-green-500">4</span>
  <span class="flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded bg-green-500">5</span>
  <span class="flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded bg-green-500">6</span>
  <span class="flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded bg-green-500">7</span>
  <span class="flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded bg-green-500">8</span>
  <span class="flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded bg-green-500">9</span>
</div>




Thanks. That works. Still see the solution I found below.

Your are looking for justify-items-center. This centers all your grid items to the center of their cell. However, item 6 still won't be at the edge of the container because item 6 doesn't occupy all the space of it's cell. Maybe ressort to grid cells with fit-content and use gap

Thanks for the replies.
I figured it out.
See here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/6zwnSAmL09
The trick is to do a custom grid-cols-[repeat(5,_1fr)_auto].
See more here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns#arbitrary-values
Also look up fr units

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Please provide more information with your answer
